# Помогите разобраться в параметре для функции mysqli_query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Помогите разобраться пожалуйста! 
Пишу простенький сниффер в учебных целях, который должен записывать данные о пользователе (ip, данные клиента, время) в Mysql базу данных. Но в следующем участке кода

```
$query = mysqli_query ($dblink, "INSERT INTO 'data' VALUES ('ip', 'usera', 'date')"); 
mysqli_query ($query, $dblink); 
mysqli_close ($dblink);
```

Возникает ошибка

```
Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in C:\OpenServer\domains\php.loc\include\sniff.php on line 14
```

переменная $dblink это подключение к самое бд, и вынесено в другой файл. К БД подключается успешно, но при запуске скрипта возникает эта ошибка.

Comment: Либо "подключается не успешно", либо переменная $dblink перезаписывается где-то по дороге. Скорее всего первое.

Answer (score 1):

Сразу после строчки коннекта сделайте вывод ошибки подключения

```
echo mysqli_connect_error();
```

PS И покажите весь код от строки подключения до mysqli_close, или хотя бы саму строку подключения

Answer (score -1):

Спасибо за помощь! Оказалось у меня были не совсем корректно заданы параметры запроса в MySQL в переменной $query

Comment: правильный ответ: вторая строчка в твоем коде - лишняя.